# Where I can get the SQL-Server 2005 C2 Audit Event List

Tags: sql-server-2005, security

I couldn't found the list of SQL-Server 2005 C2 Audit Events on google! Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link might help you

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/auditing/get-compliant-with-sql-server-2005-audit-logging/2.aspx